# Write expression to pickup specific content from a column using pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, for-loop, pattern-matching

I think I may be asking for the impossible.
I am trying to pull the following from the Notes column and remove all words left over.
The format I wish to grab is content that looks like '0-0-0' or '0 - 0 - 0'. But the expression I wrote is only grabbing row 5 & 6. I'll be eternally grateful.

```
import pandas as pd
import re as re

data = {'Notes':  ['1,088 errors  - 0 comments - 1109 pages', '76-0-143-SIS', 
                   '0 - 18 - 624  *flashcard questions (119 pgs PDF)', 
                   '0-0-1 page', '3 - 8 - 15  M1', '0 - 6 - 115', '35-0-100']}

QA_data = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Notes'])

print (QA_data)
```

And it turns out to be like the following:

```
                                              Notes
0           1,088 errors  - 0 comments - 1109 pages
1                                      76-0-143-SIS
2  0 - 18 - 624  *flashcard questions (119 pgs PDF)
3                                        0-0-1 page
4                                    3 - 8 - 15  M1
5                                       0 - 6 - 115
6                                          35-0-100
```

I used regex to build my expressions and am using pandas to pull the necessary information from a string.

```
space = re.compile('^\d+ - \d+ - \d+$')
nospace = re.compile('^\d+-\d+-\d+$')
print(checker.match("123 -123 - 123"))
```

Used a for loop to match my strings and replace everything else with ''.

```
task_dicts = QA_data.to_dict()
#print(task_dicts.keys())
#print(task_dicts["Notes"])
for keys in task_dicts["Notes"]:
    if not space.match(str(task_dicts["Notes"][keys])) and not space.match(str(task_dicts["Notes"][keys])):
        task_dicts["Notes"][keys] = ''

for keys in task_dicts["Notes"]:
   print(task_dicts["Notes"][keys])
```

Comment: why not remove all space ..then two regex become one

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `QA_data.loc[QA_data.Notes.str.contains(r'^\d\s?-\s?\d')]` (it helps if you post your desired output)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression on each element of the array.  You'll have to remove the spaces yourself though.

## `([\d ]+-){2}[\d ]+`

```js
const regExpStr = String.raw`([\d ]+-){2}[\d ]+`;
const regExp = new RegExp(regExpStr, 'g');

const data = [
  '1,088 errors  - 0 comments - 1109 pages',
  '76-0-143-SIS',
  '0 - 18 - 624  *flashcard questions (119 pgs PDF)',
  '0-0-1 page',
  '3 - 8 - 15  M1', '0 - 6 - 115', '35-0-100'
];

const matches = data.map(datum => datum.match(regExp)?.[0]);

console.log(matches);
```